# What are some cheaper alternatives to Airport Express that allow music streaming?

Tags: itunes, airport

I have a Windows desktop and laptop (no Macs) and an Airport Express for listening to music in the living room. I also have sets of speakers in two other rooms. I don't want to spend another $200 just to redirect sound to other rooms.

Is there a cheaper alternative to Airport Express that would allow me to stream music from iTunes (on a Windows computer) to these distant speakers?

(I intend to control the music playlist/volume remotely via a mobile device)

Comment: (warning shameless plug) if you're looking for multi-room audio some of these options may help: http://home4film.com/questions/10/how-can-i-set-up-a-multi-room-stereo-system-for-less-than-a-grand

Comment: Check to see what AirPlay enabled devices are coming out in November - they don't require an Airport Express.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there aren't any products other than the Airport Express that are compatible with iTunes music streaming (unless something new has come out recently). However, it's usually very easy to find a used model online for much less; I was able to pick up two of them on Craigslist for about $30 apiece. They may not be the latest model, but if all you're interested in is streaming music, then any model will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there are all sorts of wireless systems that work by plugging a cable into your mac's headphone port. The griffin iMic and others let you add another output via USB. Don't overlook Bluetooth audio like Belkin and others make.